# binary file not executing with double click on osx

Tags: macos, executable

I've compiled an executable from someone else's source code but it will only run if I launch a shell and cd into the right directory and then to `./executable.name`. But if i double click the executable I get this error 'There is no application set to open the document'.

Ive tried to do `sudo chmod -x executable.name` but that doesn't do it.

Does anyone recognise this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem was that there was a `.` in the file name that confused the system. Ive removed the `.` and it runs fine now

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.  Do you know why this happens, is it a documented bug?